# How do I get the touchpad working on a Dell Vostro 3460?

Tags: touchpad, dell-vostro

The scroll function of this touchpad does not work with Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 nor 12.10 (3.5.0-9-generic). `xinput` shows a `PS/2 Generic Mouse`.

The pointer function works well, though I cannot disable while typing.

Any hint on how to enable **multi-gesture** or just the **side scroll** on this machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you created factory image, you can mount it and find there **debs** folder. There will be all drivers for your laptop, if you didn't, [here x64](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xf37xm7wag0h5ra/wjMsZDWZfS/glidepoint_3.6-10_amd64.deb) package from my factory image for alps touchpad vostro 3460. In terminal run:

> sudo dpkg -i glidepoint_3.6-10_amd64.deb
>   
> sudo reboot

Multi-gesture are working and you can turn touchpad off by pressing **fn+F3**. Tested on ubuntu 12.04 x64 with 3.2.x and 3.3.x kernels

Comment: Have just had a chance to test it with a 3.2.0-30-generic x86_64 system. It works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have had problems with a jitterish touch pad on my Dell Latitude E6520 since Ubuntu 12.10. This finally put an end to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Synaptiks package (with a "k") and launch it. I had the same issue on my Lenovo Thinkpad. The options were available but for some reason not shown or editable in the normal mouse tools. The Synaptiks package from the Kubuntu desktop seems to be more versatile.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but did not work. When I open synaptiks, it tells me that no touchpad was detected.